# DataFrame: Creating a new column based on words in another Column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, tweets

Novice programmer here seeking help. I have a Dataframe that looks like this:

```
       Message  
0  "Blah blah $AAPL"
1  "Blah blah $ABT"      
2  "Blah blah $amzn"     
3  "Blah blah $AMZN"
4  "Blah blah $KO"
5  "Blah blah $fb"
6  "Blah blah $GOOGL"
7  "Blah blah $BA"    
8  "Blah blah $BMY"
```

My desired output is a new column that gives me the Cashtag used in the tweet, regardless if it is uppercase or lowercase. In this example it would be:

```
       Message            Cashtag
0  "Blah blah $AAPL"      "$AAPL"
1  "Blah blah $ABT"       "$ABT"
2  "Blah blah $amzn"      "$AMZN"
3  "Blah blah $AMZN"      "$AMZN"
4  "Blah blah $KO"        "$KO"
5  "Blah blah $fb"        "$FB"
6  "Blah blah $GOOGL"     "$GOOGL"
7  "Blah blah $ba"        "$BA"   
8  "Blah blah $BMY"       "$BMY"
```

How can I achieve my desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will pull the first cashtag out of any string:

```
df['Cashtag'] = df['Message'].str.extract(r'(\$[A-Za-z]{1,4})', expand=False)
```

Check out the docs for [Series.str.extract](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html#pandas.Series.str.extract).

Better yet, so you can group by cashtags later, I’d recommend also converting them to all upper case:

```
df['Cashtag'] = df['Message'].str.extract(r'(\$[A-Za-z]{1,4})', expand=False).str.upper()
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC,

```
df['Cashtag'] = df['Message'].str.upper().str.extract('(\$\w+)')
print(df)




              Message    Cashtag
0   0  "Blah blah $AAPL"   $AAPL
1    1  "Blah blah $ABT"    $ABT
2   2  "Blah blah $amzn"   $AMZN
3   3  "Blah blah $AMZN"   $AMZN
4     4  "Blah blah $KO"     $KO
5     5  "Blah blah $fb"     $FB
6  6  "Blah blah $GOOGL"  $GOOGL
7     7  "Blah blah $BA"     $BA
8    8  "Blah blah $BMY"    $BMY
```